# How to find all subnormal subgroups of a group?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is said to be subnormal in $G$ if there exists
a subnormal series from $H$ to $G$, that is a finite series
\begin{align*}
H = H_{0}\trianglelefteq H_{1}\trianglelefteq . . . \trianglelefteq H_{n} = G
\end{align*}
of subgroups of $G$, each of those is normal in the following one.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geq 2$. Find all subnormal subgroups of $S_{n}$.

Firstly, I know that for $n\geq 5$ $A_{n}$ is the only proper non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_{n}$.

For the other cases:

n=1 , $S_{1}$ has no nontrivial normal subgroups.

n=2, $S_{2}=C_{2}$ the unique group on 2 elements, so it has no nontrivial normal subgroups.
n=3, $S_{3}$ has one nontrivial proper normal subgroup, the group generated by (1 2 3).

n=4, $S_{4}$ has $A_{4}$ and $V_{4}$ being the only non-trivial proper normal subgroups of $S_{3}$.

From here, I'm not really sure how to apply the known normal subrgroups of $S_{n}$ in order to obtain all the subnormal subgroups.

I know that every abelian group is also a nilpotent group and every subgroup of a nilpotent group is subnormal. However, in this case, $S_{n}$ is only abelian if and only if $n\leq 2$.

Comment: [Please don't delete then repost like this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4681783/104041)

Comment: Every subnormal subgroup of $G$ is either normal in $G$, or subnormal in a proper normal subgroup of $G$. Lather, rinse, repeat.